# Is there an easy way to find out what topics are trending?

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

One of the daily quests is to discover all 3 trending topics for a single day. Unfortunately, I'm at a point where my videos take anywhere from 16 to 30 minutes for completion. *Without* having to wait for a video to complete, is there an easier way to discover what is trending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From personal experience, ***no***, there is no way to find out what the trending topics are aside from just trial and error.

As you progress through the game, you unlock the ability to produce multiple videos at a time, so try going through the list and you should find out the trending topics before too terribly long. Assuming the worst case scenario where every video takes 30 minutes, publishing two at a time will net you all 3 trending topics in 4 hours, at the very most.